# Dynamic SQL - Concatenated FROM table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic, ssms

Long time searcher first time poster.

I am trying to create a dynamic SQL script which concatenates the dynamic part into a string to form the From clause so I can declare the table name only once (in future I will add to this so that I can loop through a whole bunch of tables). However when I run the script I get the error: Incorrect syntax near '+'

```
DECLARE @SCode varchar(4)
DECLARE @Subcode varchar(4)

SET @SCode = 'Client1'
SET @Subcode = 'A'          
SELECT MAX(dateofchange) AS Maxdate, @SCode + 'Type'.ID 
FROM @SCode + 'Type'
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. I'm sure the answer will be simple however I am relatievely new to the SQL game.

thanks, SSMS - 2005

Comment: Which +?  remove the @SCode +'Type'.ID and see it it runs

Comment: It is the + in the From as I stripped the code all the way back to just a simple select top 1 * from and it errors. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this dynamic SQL script(option for a SQLServer2008+)

```
DECLARE @SCode varchar(10) = 'Client1',
        @Subcode varchar(10) = 'A',
        @dml nvarchar(400)
SELECT @dml = 'SELECT MAX(dateofchange) AS Maxdate, ID FROM ' + QUOTENAME( + @SCode + 'Type')
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```

Comment: Please see my additional answer below for the working code and an explanation as to why these changes need to be made.

Answer (score 3):

Using the answer from Alexander Fedorenko in SQl Server 2005 it gives an error "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable." and then for every variable "Must declare the scalar variable "@dml""

The reason for this is that with 2005 you have to declare the variable and set in like

```
DECLARE @SCode AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @scode ='ID12'
```

I simplified the example a however the below code is a working example for SSMS 2005

```
DECLARE @dml  as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SCode AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @scode ='ID12'
Set @dml='SELECT ID 
FROM '+ QUOTENAME(+@SCode +'Type')
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```

Side Note: Why you can't comment on an answer with a code block is beyond me.

Comment: Very valuable info.Thanks @Richard and +1 in your answer;)

Comment: Thanks and now I have enough rep to be able to plus 1 your answer too.